# arcgis server 10, vb.net, adding dynamic data

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, web-mapping, vb.net, dynamic-layer

i am using arcgis server 10, with visual web developer 2010 express edition. i downloaded "ArcGIS_AddDynamicData_VBNet\Default_ADF.aspx" project form [ArcGIS Add dynamic data for ArcGIS Server 10](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/serveradf_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00020000011p000000). everything works fine, now instead of the simple display they have in there i wanted to add the "web mapping application template". so what i really want is to have the same functionality shown in the project but with the default "web mapping application template". plz can you tell me how i could possibly integrate the default web mapping application template into that project? thanks a lot in advance!!!